# Can i use a high ampere battery power bank than my tab's actual input

Tags: power, input

I recently bought a new battery power bank but its output is 5V 3.1A.
But my tab's input is 5V 2.0A. Is it completely safe to use it with my tab or is there any danger or risk.

Answer (score 2):

It is completely safe, the 3.1A capability is there, but the tablet, or any other device you connect to the power bank, will draw the correct amount of current for itself.

Comment: Oh now i get it.

Comment: That is why it is written Output 3.1A (MAX)